# keepass-file: where should i store this file?

Tags: linux, keepass

Where would you recommend me to store the Keepass-file?  Well - for most of the use-cases usually i have all my personal documents in my cloud account. 
The pro:  i can access it from everywhere in the world. With any device.

But besides that i am not so sure if this is safe. Especially if it comes to such things like keepass: Some friends mentioned that it is not so safe: 
Question; would it be safe to use the cloud for the keepass-file? Can i secure it even further, by adding another (extra) layer of security by encrypting the file. 
the generalized question is this: How safe is it to store the keepass-file in the (wrong place) like in the cloud? What risks do I need to know about?
What can I do with the KeePass password file, there are several arguments to decide where to store it. if the passwords are really, really important to someone, 
one should make the decision based on:

- the possible risk of the file being hacked by some hackers - what can we do if we consider to get hacked
- what if someone may compromise the file just with a hack
- is it preferable that the DB file not get in the wild,
- there may be more and other terrible risks - which one do you take into consideration"?

so there some difficult questions arise: What should i do - what can be  done with the passwd. 
Can I secure it even further, by adding another extra layer of security by encrypting the file i am going to store in cloud storage online.
look forward to hear from you

Well i guess: The best place to store the Keepass DB file is wherever it is most convenient for someone.
With a sufficiently strong and arbitrarily defined password - like so: 3112-.,,2-1^^^ and so forth.
Well i think that we should make use of a long password (30+ characters) well one that is not guessable outside of brute force

Belive it or not: i have heared that some like storing the Keepass DB in Google Drive.
Question; is this not a big big security hole!?

the pros of this method: 
- it allows one to easily access the DB from both the phone and the laptops. 
- it also is automatically versioned every time one does update it

Comment: You're looking for a bunch of ideas or suggestions on how to protect your file. There is no way to really figure out the best method for you, since we are not you. This is something you're going to need to think about and figure out on your own.

Comment: Here's a stupid simple suggestion, put it on a thumb drive and put the thumb drive in a physical safe, lockbox, bank vault. Put the drive in a zip lock bag and dig it somewhere in the yard in the middle of the night, and make a map of where the drive is buried and then eat the map. :) you see? Figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have missed the Keepass documentation. You will find the infos you are looking for on the official website [keepass.info](https://keepass.info).

https://keepass.info/help/base/security.html
https://keepass.info/help/base/faq_tech.html
https://keepass.info/help/base/keys.html

> *what can be done with the passwd. Can I secure it even further*

yes. see Keepass website. eg https://keepass.info/help/v2/dbsettings.html

> The best place to store the Keepass DB file is wherever it is most convenient for someone. With a sufficiently strong and arbitrarily defined password - like so: 3112-.,,2-1^^^ and so forth.

Idem (see masterkey + keyfile). There are several methods to increase the security level of your Keepass DB.

> Belive it or not: i have heared that some like storing the Keepass DB in Google Drive. Question; is this not a big big security hole!?

Yes it's quite common and "ok" if you take the adequate security measures (eg masterkey+keyfile). Better is to never upload sensitive date to cloud imho.. It's always a deal between security and day to day usability but the Keepass DB is encrypted, your cloud account is encrypted and if you use masterkey + keyfile it should be fine.

From Keepass website:

> A KeePass database is a regular file, which users can store wherever they want. KeePass does not require Internet/cloud access. Anyway, some users prefer to store their database file in a public place (such as a shared network drive, a webserver, a cloud storage like e.g. Dropbox, ...), in order to always have access to their database whenever an Internet connection is available.
>
> If you use a strong master key, storing the database file in a public place is not a problem.
>
> When opening a database file, KeePass loads the complete database file
> (in encrypted form) into its process memory and decrypts it there. All
> work (like editing an entry, creating a group, etc.) is performed with
> the data in process memory. When the 'Save' command is invoked,
> KeePass encrypts the data and sends the encrypted data to disk/server.
> This means that your data is transferred and stored only in encrypted
> form; the disk/server and network never see your unencrypted data.

You may also be interested by
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keepass?sort=newest&page=2&pagesize=15.